# Using a View in a tooltip for an image map hover link

Tags: 7, views, tooltips

I have a **imagemap** with various  tags, it works well in my Drupal instance, I can click on the various areas to get to my pages.

Now I want to hover one area and display a **tooltip** with information inside (example: if I hover France, I will have a tooltip showing little information on Paris, with a picture). I will find myself how to do it by the way if you can't help with it - that's just my final goal.

Following various sites tutorials, I made a View with contextual filters in order to display the city content by passing an argument to the view. It works like a charm. I also rewrote the output to use tokens for display

I have actually no idea **how to display my View in a tooltip** - and searching didn't help me either ...

Modules I am using :

- Views
- Tipsy (or qTip or else, I don't have any preferences, as long as it works)

Comment: It is not possible to show the whole view in a tooltip

Comment: You can display the view fields in tool tip, but not the whole views.

Comment: OK can you please explain to me how I display the view fields ? I can't see how it works ...

Comment: I done it with https://drupal.org/project/beautytips module. have a look at this, if have a idea to use it, then i will tell you the steps.

Comment: OK so I installed the Beautytips module and configured the UI to fit my needs. Can you tell me the steps ?

Comment: While waiting for you answer, I found out this page : http://www.wootenswebdesign.com/quick-and-easy-beauty-tips which is exactly what I am trying to do - but it is Drupal 6 compliant, and he uses Custom Field module which is deprecated in Drupal 7.

How can I achieve this result in D7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `replacement patterns` to achieve something similar.
Add the fields you would want as the view and then in replacement pattern you can `render a views block` or even customize the display via `html`.